# 'Contains' predicate using Hazelcast

Tags: sql, hazelcast, predicate, nosql

'Contains' predicate using Hazelcast

I have a field of type List in an IMap. I would like to check if a string value is in the list. What would be the correct approach to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast 3.7 has support for collection queries based on the new `ValueExtractor` API. One of the default implementations supports queries to simulate your contains request (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#indexing-in-collections-and-arrays).

The query you're looking for would be as simple as:

```
Predicate p = Predicates.equals('users[any]', 'Peter');
```

Anyhow you should combine it with an index (depending on the amount of objects):

```
<indexes>
  <index ordered="false">users[any]</index>
</indexes>
```